# Count distinct days in a month of a group table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm working on a dashboard that requires some values groups according to year and month. In this case, I'm grouping in Power Query a table that sums a variable for each month-year
Like this:
[image]
But I need one more column that counts the days in a month and year of the table according to the data.
This is the data:
[image]

I need, for example, the year 2022 and the month "diciembre" counts as 3 days (because are the distinct days of the month 12 that the company worked).  An example of the expected result:
[image]
I tried the power query "count distinct rows" option per month but it doesn't work.
I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

go back to to the group by step and add a new aggregations as below-

[image]

This will add the Power Query as below-

[image]

Now just change the **Table** to a **List**, and add the **Date** column name as below and hopefully you will get your desired output in a new column-

[image]